# Не получается вставить текст .setText("usd");

Tags: java, android, textview, adapter, cursor

Создаю список из БД, при этом пытаюсь найти `TextView` в другом `Layout` (item.xml), чтобы вставить в него текст. 
Почему при запуске `TextView` пустое?

```
protected void insertElementOfListFromBase(){          
    View itemLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item, null); // 
    TextView money_unit = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.money_unit);   
    money_unit.setText("usd");          
    String[] from = new String[] { SCHETCHIK, STIOMOST };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.number, R.id.printStoimost };

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);
    Spisok = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisok);
    Spisok.setAdapter(scAdapter);
}
```

Comment: прошу прощения, я новичок в java, но не забыли ли вы превратить `itemLayout` в View?  `View itemLayout = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.item, null); `

Answer (score 2):

Вы создаете `View`:

```
View itemLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item, null); //
```

Делаете с ним манипуляции:

```
View itemLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item, null); // 
TextView money_unit = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.money_unit);   
money_unit.setText("usd");
```

И никуда его не добавляете. Вы просто не выводите его на экран.

Comment: А как его можно вывести? До этого у меня был текст в xml файле в TextView c id money_unit. Сейчас его нужно менять программно.

Comment: @Alexander, дайте больше кода. вы же ничего не показываете.